# Unable to allocate Java Heaps Space more than 1024m

Tags: java, windows, neo4j, out-of-memory

I am using a 64 bit Windows machine. I am trying to run a java `dropwizard` application that references a `Neo4` database server but the initialization fails with an out of memory error

I tried setting the heap size but I cant set it to be more than 1024M. How do I debug this issue?

The machine has 32Gb RAM and the database is 60GB on a network drive

Comment: Nothing to debug. Install a 64-bit version of Java. 32-bit programs can generally only allocate about 1.6 Gb of memory, even if run on 64-bit machines.

Comment: please share the VM args you are using

Comment: Thank you Andreas, changing JVM to 64 bit fixed it

Comment: Please check whether you have 32-bit version of Java running on that machine, and if yes, remove it and install a 64-bit version as @Andreas pointed out